# Schaum's General Topology, exercise 4.11 - what am I missing?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

In Schaum's *General Topoplogy* exercise 11 in chapter 4 we find the following task:

> Prove: A set $F$ is closed if and only if its complement $F^c$ is open.

This is all that the exercise says; there are no assumptions on $F$ provided. The book defines closedness in the following way:

> A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a *closed set* iff its complement $A^c$ is an open set.

What I cannot understand is what the exercise is asking of me. If the set $F$ in the exercise is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then there is nothing to prove, since it is true by definition, right?

However, if the intention of the author is for $F$ to be a subset of some other set, I cannot see how this could be done, since open and closed sets are only defined for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ as per chapter 4. The main material of the book starts from chapter 5, but from what I understand from my "sneak peek" of the later parts of the book, "open" and "closed" need to be defined in terms of some topology, but here all we know that $F$ is a set, but we don't know in what topological space it lives (right?).

I'm sure that there is some thing that I'm overlooking, but I cannot see what it might be. I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Looks like the book had a sloppy proofreading.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I suspected it, but usually when I find an "error", it turns out that I have missed some point, so I'm always cautious to make claims about errors in books. Thank you so much for confirming this!

Comment: I really like the style of the book overall in that it makes you prove each theorem as an exercise, rather than just have us memorize the proofs, so I hope there aren't more of this kind of "exercise" in there xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this answer, be sure to read Mark Bennet's subsequent comment + my reactive comment.

---

For what it is worth, the **definition** that I was taught is that $F$ is closed $\iff F^c$ is open.

**However**, based on this definition, consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology).

One of the consequences of the definition that I was taught is 
$E_1$ An open set never contains any of its boundary points.

From this, it is easy to see that a closed set contains all of its boundary points (if any).

I have also seen the **definition** of an open set to be a set that contains none of its boundary points, and the **definition** of a closed set to be a set that contains all of its boundary points.

Under this alternative set of definitions, it is meaningful
to (for example) 
pronounce $F$ as an open set and ask you to prove that $F^c$ is a closed set.

Comment: I think some of these comments on boundary points are misleading in a general context. For example in a set with the discrete topology every subset is both open and closed. And in a set which is not connected, any connected component is both open and closed.

Comment: @MarkBennet Very good point.  My knowledge of topology is **very limited** and is confined to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}.$  I will add a caveat to my answer re your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction @user2661923. I think your point is a good one. The definition I learned for open and closed sets that I learned when studying mathematics for the first time was based on sets and their boundary points. I think it is interesting that depending on what definition you choose, what qualifies as a theorem or indeed a meaningful question can change.

Comment: Thank you also for the comment @MarkBennet. As I'm just about to dive into the "actual" general topology sometime later this week, I will think more about your comment a little bit later when I have more knowledge about topology!

Answer (score 1):

I checked the book, and you are right that they just re-state their definition.

The exercise is:

> Prove: A set $F$ is closed if and only if its complement $F^c$ is
> open.

And their solution to that exercise is:

> Note that $(F^c)^c = F$, so $F$ is the complement of $F^c$. Thus, by
> definition, $F$ is closed iff $F^c$ is open.

What I *think they were thinking* is:

"Ok, so we defined a closed set to be a set whose complement is open. Now we state an exercise that shows exactly what these sets look like."

This would be why their solution involves noting that the complement of a complement of a set is the set itself - but apparently they forgot that they did define a set to be closed in exactly the way stated by the exercise.